# Are there no solutions for $\begin {cases} 2x+4y = 6\\ 3x+6y = 5\end {cases}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I'm trying to solve an equation system using Gauss-Jordan.

$$\begin {cases}  2x+4y = 6\\ 3x+6y = 5\end {cases}$$

So, first, the augmented matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
2&4&5\\
3&6&6\\
\end{bmatrix}

I want to reduce it to the "staggered reduced form" (how is that called?), so I start:

$$-f_1+f_2$$

\begin{bmatrix}
2&4&5\\
1&2&1\\
\end{bmatrix}

$$-2f_2+f_1$$

\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&3\\
1&2&1\\
\end{bmatrix}

$$f_1f_2$$

\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1\\
0&0&3\\
\end{bmatrix}

Then, I would transform that $3$ into a $1$ and *somehow* get rid of the $2$ and $1$ from the first row (not sure how) to complete the reduction, yes?

However, look at the last row: $0, 0, 3$. That's to say

$$0x+0y=3$$

Does that mean that the equation system **has no solutions**?

Comment: Your system is equivalent to $6x+12y=18$ and $6x+12y=10$.  These cannot be both true at the same time.  Your system has no solutions.

Comment: You have it almost. You just need to realize that there are no real numbers $x,y$ such that $0x+0y=3$. Therefore this no solution this system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide the original equations by $2$ and $3$ respectively. Then they both specify the value of $x+2y$, but the values differ.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed no solutions.  This makes sense:  the two equations describe lines in $\mathbb{R^2}$.  Note that they are parallel, so there can be no intersection points.

Answer (score 1):

The lines are parallel, so there are no solutions.

The lines are: $y = -\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{2}$, and $y = -\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{5}{6}$. Graph them and you will see they never intersect.

Answer (score 1):

If you've had determinants, you find that the determinant of the coefficient matrix is $ \ \left| \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 4  \\ 3 & 6  \end{array} \right| \ = \ 0 \ ,  $  which is already a sign that you have either a dependent or inconsistent system.  Row-reduction or any of the other techniques given by the other posters then establish that "Inconsistency, *it is!*"